# What is the best way to compute a rolling (lag and lead) difference in sales?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, iteration, rolling-computation

I'm looking to add a field or two into my data set that represents the difference in sales from the last week to current week and from current week to the next week.

My dataset is about 4.5 million rows so I'm looking to find an efficient way of doing this, currently I'm getting into a lot of iteration and for loops and I'm quite sure I'm going about this the wrong way. but Im trying to write code that will be reusable on other datasets and there are situations where you might have nulls or no change in sales week to week (therefore there is no record)

The dataset looks like the following:

```
Store  Item  WeekID  WeeklySales
1      1567   34      100.00
2      2765   34      86.00
3      1163   34      200.00
1      1567   35      160.00
.      .
.      . 
.      .
```

I have each week as its own dictionary and then each store sales for that week in a dictionary within. So I can use the week as a key and then within the week I access the store's dictionary of item sales.

```
weekly_sales_dict = {}
for i in df['WeekID'].unique():
    store_items_dict = {}
    subset = df[df['WeekID'] == i]
    subset = subset.groupby(['Store', 'Item']).agg({'WeeklySales':'sum'}).reset_index()
    for j in subset['Store'].unique():
        storeset = subset[subset['Store'] == j]
        store_items_dict.update({str(j): storeset})
    weekly_sales_dict.update({ str(i) : store_items_dict})
```

Then I iterate through each week in the weekly_sales_dict and compare each store/item within it to the week behind it (I planned to do the same for the next week as well). The 'lag_list' I create can be indexed by week, store, and Item so I was going to iterate through and add the values to my df as a new lag column but I feel I am way overthinking this.

```
count = 0 
key_list = list(df['WeekID'].unique())
lag_list = []
for k,v in weekly_sales_dict.items():
    if count != 0 and count != len(df['WeekID'].unique())-1:
        prev_wk = weekly_sales_dict[str(key_list[(count - 1)])]
        current_wk = weekly_sales_dict[str(key_list[count])
        for i in df['Store'].unique():
            prev_df = prev_wk[str(i)]
            current_df = current_wk[str(i)]
            for j in df['Item'].unique():
                print('in j')
                if j in list(current_df['Item'].unique()) and j in list(prev_df['Item'].unique()):
                    item_lag = current_df[current_df['Item'] == int(j)]['WeeklySales'].values - prev_df[prev_df['Item'] == int(j)]['WeeklySales'].values
                    df[df['Item'] == j][df['Store'] == i ][df['WeekID'] == key_list[count]]['lag'] = item_lag[0]
                    lag_list.append((str(i),str(j),item_lag[0]))
                elif j in list(current_df['Item'].unique()):
                    item_lag = current_df[current_df['Item'] == int(j)]['WeeklySales'].values
                    lag_list.append((str(i),str(j),item_lag[0]))
                else:
                    pass
        count += 1
    else:            
        count += 1
```

Comment: have you looked at `pd.DataFrame.rolling()`?

Comment: I had looked at it but the examples seemed to focus on dates to determine the period, since I'm using week IDs I thought I might have to go a different route

Comment: I can work on a solution in about 4 hours, if there's no answer by then

Comment: I forgot! are you still stuck?

Comment: no worries! I have not made any progress on this.... I was going to try pd.rolling() today but the examples aren't quite making sense to me.

Comment: ok, I might have a window soon

Comment: I ended up solving it in a much simpler manner

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I was about to start working on it. It's ok to post an aswer for your own question, so feel encouraged to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.diff()` the problem was solved. I sorted all rows by week, then created a subset with a multi-index by grouping on store,items,and week. Finally I used pd.diff() with a period of 1 and I ended up with the sales difference from the current week to the week prior.

```
df = df.sort_values(by = 'WeekID')

subset = df.groupby(['Store', 'Items', 'WeekID']).agg({''WeeklySales'':'sum'})
subset['lag']  = subset[['WeeklySales']].diff(1)
```